# Count number of days in each continuous period pandas

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, count

Suppose I have next df `N03_zero` (`date_code` is already `datetime`):

```
item_code       date_code
8028558104973   2022-01-01
8028558104973   2022-01-02
8028558104973   2022-01-03
8028558104973   2022-01-06
8028558104973   2022-01-07
7622300443269   2022-01-01
7622300443269   2022-01-10
7622300443269   2022-01-11
513082          2022-01-01
513082          2022-01-02
513082          2022-01-03
```

Millions of rows with `date_code` assigned to some `item_code`.
I am trying to get the number of days of each continuous period for each `item_code`, all other similar questions doesn't helped me.
The expected df should be:

```
item_code       continuous_days
8028558104973   3
8028558104973   2
7622300443269   1
7622300443269   2
513082          3
```

Once days sequence breaks, it should count days in this sequence and then start to count again.
The aim is, to able to get then the dataframe with `count`, `min`, `max`, and `mean` for each `item_code`.

Like this:

```
item_code       no. periods   min   max   mean
8028558104973   2             2     3     2.5
7622300443269   2             1     2     1.5
513082          1             3     3     3
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For consecutive days compare difference by [`Series.diff`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.diff.html) in days by [`Series.dt.days`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.days.html) for not equal `1` by [`Series.ne`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.ne.html) with cumulative sum by [`Series.cumsum`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.cumsum.html) and then use [`GroupBy.size`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.size.html), remove second level by [`DataFrame.droplevel`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.droplevel.html) and create `DataFrame`:

```
df['date_code'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date_code'])

df1= (df.groupby(['item_code',df['date_code'].diff().dt.days.ne(1).cumsum()], sort=False)
        .size()
        .droplevel(1)
        .reset_index(name='continuous_days'))
print (df1)
       item_code  continuous_days
0  8028558104973                3
1  8028558104973                2
2  7622300443269                1
3  7622300443269                2
4         513082                3
```

And then aggregate values by named aggregations by [`GroupBy.agg`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.agg.html):

```
df2 = (df1.groupby('item_code', sort=False, as_index=False)
          .agg(**{'no. periods': ('continuous_days','size'),
                 'min':('continuous_days','min'),
                 'max':('continuous_days','max'),
                 'mean':('continuous_days','mean')}))
print (df2)
       item_code  no. periods  min  max  mean
0  8028558104973            2    2    3   2.5
1  7622300443269            2    1    2   1.5
2         513082            1    3    3   3.0
```

Comment: Thank you so much, in first it doesn't work as my real row data was sorted by `date_code` only, so it goes like ~60k items for 1st day, then ~60k items for 2nd etc. Once I sorted it both for `item_code` and `date_code` as provided in sample, it works. Thank you!